# Jquery UI Datepicker altField input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two inputs with datepicker, I need that first datepicker can initialize another, this works great with `altField`, but the datepicker from the second input does not work anymore. I make a example with this data:

https://jsfiddle.net/5njLoxd5/

```
<input type="text" id="lightBillingStartdate" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="lightBillingFinishDate" /><br/>

$( "#lightBillingStartdate" ).datepicker({
    altField: "#lightBillingFinishDate",
    altFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    maxDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#lightBillingFinishDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);
    }        
});

$( "#lightBillingFinishDate" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    maxDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
                $("#lightBillingStartdate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected);
    } 
});
```

Comment: The example works for me.

Comment: You change the first datepicker and works, Then, try change the second date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `setDate` method like so: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5njLoxd5/2/

```
$("#lightBillingStartdate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  maxDate: 0,
  onSelect: function(selected) {
    $("#lightBillingFinishDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
    $("#lightBillingFinishDate").datepicker("setDate", selected);
  }
});

$("#lightBillingFinishDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  maxDate: 0,
  onSelect: function(selected) {
    $("#lightBillingStartdate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
  }
});
```

Comment: It's a good snippet, I was mind-closed thinking about altField :) Thanks

Comment: Welcome. The `altField` option only places the text in the field. `setDate` updates the UI Object properly.